# BT137 triac turns-on uncommanded

Tags: opto-isolator, triac, snubber

I am working with the following circuit, which is from the [MOC3043M datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/MOC3043M-D.pdf) with a BT137 at the location of the unnamed triac:

[image: Page 7, MOC3043 data sheet]

This circuit works fine for me **if** I leave the snubber out. However, with the snubber in place, the BT137 is on all the time.

I would look forward to any suggestions as to why this is happening.

Comment: What exactly is your load **when you are making the measurement**? And are you using the exact values in the schematic?

Comment: Load during testing is: no load or a 3w LED bulb.

Comment: Two snubber configurations tried:
1. As shown 39R/0.01uF
2. Roxburgh RE1201 (120R/0.1uF)

Answer (score 1):

Reduce the snubber capacitor value to 100nf and maintain the resistor value 30R to 50R(play around with the value).
Also make sure you are not swapping ANODE 1 and ANODE 2 terminal of the triac , because this will cause it to turn on always

Answer (score 0):

I have placed a 0.47uF/450v cap across the 330R (cold side) resistor.
Tested by repeatedly applying 240vac while heating (50 degrees C - the max temp my wife's hairdryer will go!) the triac.
No miss-firing that I could detect.